# How to disable a trail camera with a laser

Tags: security-theater

My neighbor presently has a version of a Stealth Cam P12 6 MP Trail Camera 9 (see link below) pointed directly into my windows.  Rather than get into a legal argument (the authorities where I live won't care and I am not in the habit on contacting the police unless it is life-or-death), can I permanently disable this kind of camera by burning out the CMOS with a green Laser Pointer Pen 532 nM?

IF not, are there any other suggestions on how I might disable it without trespassing?

http://www.cabelas.com/product/Stealth-Cam-P-MP-Trail-Camera/1816967.uts?productVariantId=3889805&srccode=cii_17588969&cpncode=41-52786984-2&WT.tsrc=CSE&WT.mc_id=GoogleProductAds&WT.z_mc_id1=03913739&rid=20

Comment: You are aware that destroying his property is illegal, right?

Comment: You could defeat it with high tech measures, such as ringing the outside of your window with superbright IR LEDs.  This would blind the camera such that it couldn't see your activities. You could also defeat it with low tech measures, such as curtains.  Or you could walk over there and ask him to get rid of it.

Comment: I know you don't want to get into a legal argument, but other actions may land you in legal trouble.  If the authorities don't care consider talking to an attorney in the US you can probably get a cease and desist, not sure about other countries.

Comment: The manual for that camera is [available online](http://www.gsmoutdoors.com/downloads/file/5b78175d-34fe-4e4d-b468-96a9fe3a1433/). Depending on how big a memory card is in there, you may be able to trigger enough photos to fill it up quickly.

Comment: This is one of those "consult your lawyer" legal matters. Pointing a surveillance camera through your neighbor's bedroom window has certain ramifications. On the bright side, the reviews for that particular camera say its kind of dodgy, poor night images and flaky triggering at 30 feet. Could always buy one and see how poor the infrared filter is, then you could do an invisible, non-invasive IR counterattack. NOTE: Infrared only works as well as the camera's UV/IR filtration works. Good filtration/iris system, no point. Pointing a laser? Pfft. It will get three good identifying shots of you.

Answer (score 3):

It is improbable that a basic laser pointer will "burn out the CMOS" -- the power conveyed by a laser pointer, even though concentrated on a small surface, is small when compared to that would be achieved by pointing the camera towards the Sun, and I expect the camera to resist such occasional pointing.

Unless, of course, you have decided not to stop at breaking *one* law, and go for some high-powered (but not legally sold) laser.

Speaking of which, remotely destroying other people's hardware is still a kind of "trespass". The Law is not a video game; it is not defeated by using a magic loophole. Besides complaining with the police forces, your only non-illegal option for retaliation is to be so ugly and do things so utterly boring that your neighbour will switch off his camera in disgust.